# How to implement Cognito with/without Amplify on pure HTML & JS?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-cognito

I've read most of the docs provided by `AWS` but they're specifically for `React JS`.

I'm trying to implement the sign-in, sign-up & login part but I am getting confused on how this whole thing works.

I found this '[barebones](https://github.com/gravitybacklight/aws-cognito-barebones-js)' method of implementing `Cognito` where the user implemented `Cognito` without `Amplify & hosted UI`, but I'm not quite sure if this is the secure way of doing it.

Is there anyone who implemented `Cognito` with/without `Amplify` on the hosted `UI/own` custom `UI`?

Would appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this matter as I've been scratching my head over this for the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cognito identity SDK found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js)